# Delete com Subquery no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, query, delete

Tenho a seguinte tabela (Exemplo), onde o usuário de ID **151** possui 2 registros:

| id (Primary Key) | usuario_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 151 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 3 | 985 |
| 4 | 151 |
| 5 | 652 |

Preciso deletar os 2 registros desse usuário. O problema é que como a coluna **usuario_id** não possui Primary Key, o MySQL não permite por conta do safe update. Precisava contornar isso sem precisar mexer nas configurações.

Tentei das seguintes maneiras, porém, sem sucesso, o erro persiste.

```
DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 = 151);
```

```
DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 = 151);
```

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta !

Comment: Também esta confuso... `DELETE FROM tabela WHERE usuario_id = '151'` não resolveria o problema? Vai apagar todos os registros onde `usuario_id` seja 151.

Comment: Foi o que eu falei, o MySQL não permite, pois a coluna usuario_id não possui Primary Key

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com `Primary Key`, qual é o erro?

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: Execute `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`. Após execute o `DELETE`.

Comment: `DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id = 151` não resolve?

Comment: se for a mesma tabela está só complicando, pode fazer como comentado aqui, `DELETE FROM tabela WHERE usuario_id= 151`, se forem duas tabelas, seu exemplo está ruim, pois no from ambas se chamam "tabela" o que induz ao erro

Comment: A resposta do Clarck funcionou, o restante não conseguiu entender a pergunta, mas agradeço mesmo assim.

Comment: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` é recomendado apenas para executar numa tool, no workbench por exemplo, não para por no código, se for usar esse delete no código vai precisar mudar isso

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, percebi isso. Abri uma outra pergunta focando mais no assunto, se puder ajudar, agradeço: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514150/deletar-registro-sem-primary-key-no-mysql-via-ajax

Comment: Não é porque a resposta dele resolveu que esta correta, isso funcionou por coincidência, desligar o SAFE_UPDATES nem deveria ser uma resposta, isso ficou mais como "suporte técnico" e também não tem sentido executar uma subquery sem necessidade, sendo que as colunas são especificas para os mesmos registros, simplesmente tem algo errado, é muito mais provavel que o problema só esta ocorrendo porque existem dados em outras tabelas relacionadas com chaves estrangeiras, ou seja, para excluir um registro na tabela A tem que eliminar os "vinculados".

Comment: ... mas independente disso a pergunta não apresenta detalhes claros para que alguém consiga resolver de forma objetiva e para que a pergunta sirva a futuros usuários. Temos anos de experiência aqui e por isso foi criado o [guia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/3635), para auxiliar a atuar no site de forma proveitosa para si mesmo, assim como para futuros visitantes, tornando o conteudo em algo claro e proveitoso.

Answer (score 0):

> Preciso deletar os 2 registros desse usuário. O problema é que como a
> coluna usuario_id não possui Primary Key, o MySQL não permite por
> conta do safe update. Precisava contornar isso sem precisar mexer nas
> configurações.

É possível desabilitar o *SAFE UPDATE*, executar o comando *DELETE* e reabilitar a restrição.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 = 151);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```